# Is there a way to identify floating NaN and then replacing them in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I tried to identify NaNs in my dataframe and later removed them as they weren't necessary for this particular problem. Although now while performing another operation, I came across something called "floating NaN" and because of that I'm unable to do this operation.

```
transaction id
54789
56334
56233
58789
C57832
C53347
C58963
C58797
```

The operation which I was performing involved identifying integers and strings in this column and add a new column which would have "Ordered" if integers, and "Cancelled" if strings. For this operation I used following code.

```
data_clean['transaction status'] = data_clean['transaction id'].str.isnumeric().astype(int)
```

the above line of code would have given me the output as

```
  transaction id  transaction status
0         654656                   1
1         546466                   1
2         654646                   1
3         844886                   1
4        C846464                   0
5        C384448                   0
6        C468788                   0
7        C873316                   0
```

for this line of code, I get the following error.

```
cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

I didn't know until this point that floating NaNs existed until this point. How do i detect them? The first time i tried running

```
data_clean['trasaction id'].isnull().any()
```

it came as

```
False
```

How do i find such floating NaNs if the above line of code couldn't detect?

Comment: You might try `.isna()` instead of `.isnull()` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html

Comment: Your method works for me. Which pandas version are you on? `print(pd.__version__)`?

Comment: @aylr there's no difference between `isna()` or `isnull()`.

Comment: @aylr i tried both, it went undetected. it returned `False`.:(

Comment: @Erfan I am using 0.25.0 on IBM Cognitive Labs

Comment: Use: `data_clean['transaction status'] = np.where(pd.to_numeric(data_clean['transaction id'], errors='coerce').notna(), 1, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
data_clean['transaction status'] = pd.notna(pd.to_numeric(data_clean['transaction id', errors='coerce')).astype(int)
```

First, `pd.to_numeric` converts the column to a numeric format. Because you've got strings in the rows when the transaction is cancelled, these get picked up as errors. Setting `errors=coerce` will give you a NaN for those rows.

Second, with `pd.notna`, NaNs get set to False and numbers get set to True.

Third, `astype(int)` converts True/False to 1/0.